# DataFrame object has no attribute insert

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

While running this command 
`dupedWithColsDF = dupedDF.insert(loc=len(dupedDF.columns), 
                                  column='lcFirstName', 
                                  value=lower(firstName))`

I get the error: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'insert'

Also, I try to insert a new column into the dataframe like this:

```
dupedWithColsDF = dupedDF.assign (lcFirstName = lower(firstName), 
                             lcLastName = lower(lastName), 
                             lcMiddleName = lower(middleName))
```

I get the error: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'assign'

Could anyone advise how to fix it and how to add new columns to the dataframe?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Neither of those are Spark df attributes - see [this post](https://towardsdatascience.com/5-ways-to-add-a-new-column-in-a-pyspark-dataframe-4e75c2fd8c08) on how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to add a column to a dataframe you should use withColumn:

```
df.withColumn('age2', df.age + 2).collect()
[Row(age=2, name='Alice', age2=4), Row(age=5, name='Bob', age2=7)]
```

basically you can just do this for the example you posted:

```
dupedWithColsDF = dupedDF.withColumn("lcFirstName", lower(dupedDF.firstName)).withColumn("lcLastName", lower(dupedDF.lastName)).
withColumn("middleName", lower(dupedDF.middleName))
```

you can take a look here to understand the api to use and which are supported:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.pandas_udf